# Плагин карусели Slick. Проблема с плавностью анимации

Tags: jquery, slider, slick.js, carousel

Здравствуйте.

Проблема в следующем: css-анимация прокрутки слайдов с плагине Slick выполняется рывками. Оказалось, что плавность анимации обеспечивается добавлением скриптом вот этих стилей:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ума не приложу, почему, но у меня эти стили не добавляются в процессе работы плагина. Файл стилей плагина подключен.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проблема решена. Оказалось нужно обязательно передавать параметр useTransform со значением true при инициализации плагина. И это несмотря на то, что в документации указано, что true - это дефолтное значение параметра, и на демке на сайте разработчика анимация работает, как нужно на вызове slick() без параметров.

Answer (score 3):

Проблема решена. Оказалось нужно **обязательно** передавать параметр *useTransform* со значением *true* при инициализации плагина. И это несмотря на то, что в документации указано, что *true* - это дефолтное значение параметра, и на демке на сайте разработчика анимация работает, как нужно на вызове *slick()* без параметров.